# How to identify chunks to decompress before an insert?

Tags: compression, timescaledb

Timescaledb docs show how to decompress a specific chunk:

```
SELECT decompress_chunk('chunk_name');
```

or all chunks for a given hypertable:

```
SELECT decompress_chunk(show_chunks('hypertable_name'));
```

However, that implies that you either need to know which chunk is going to be inserted into or are ok with decompressing the entire table. I am working with a large table  (> 100 GB uncompressed). Decompressing an entire table is impractical in this case, especially that it has an additional dimension (which is used in chunking alongside the timestamp).

Is it possible to find chunks that are relevant to my query given datetime & dimension ranges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** The answer is tested on TimescaleDB 1.7.

Specific chunk, which matches time and space dimension values, can be found with help of `show_chunk`, public informational views, which are in schema `timescaledb_information`, and internal catalog tables, which are in `_timescaledb_catalog`.

First, `show_chunk` has optional parameters `older_than` and `newer_than`, which allows to find chunks, which older or newer than the chunk with the give timestamp, and then subtracted from all chunks. For example:

```sql
SELECT c.chunk_name
FROM (SELECT show_chunks('hyper') AS chunk_name
    EXCEPT (SELECT show_chunks('hyper', older_than => '2018-07-02 06:01'::timestamptz))
    EXCEPT (SELECT show_chunks('hyper', newer_than => '2018-07-02 06:01'::timestamptz))) AS c
```

To retrieve only compressed chunk `compression_status = 'Compressed'` on `timescaledb_information.compressed_chunk_stats` will help.

If a space dimension is also defined on the hypertable, the above query will return the same number of chunks as the number of partitions on the space dimension. To find correct dimension it is necessary to check to which chunk the space dimension value belongs and the space dimension ranges are stored in `_timescaledb_catalog.dimension_slice`. **An example of the final query is at the end.**

Let's take an example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE hyper(
    time timestamptz NOT NULL, 
    device int, 
    value float
);
SELECT * FROM create_hypertable('hyper', 'time', 'device', 2);

ALTER TABLE hyper SET (timescaledb.compress, 
                       timescaledb.compress_segmentby='device', 
                       timescaledb.compress_orderby = 'time DESC');

INSERT INTO hyper VALUES
       ('2017-01-01 06:01', 1, 1.2),
       ('2017-01-01 09:11', 3, 4.3),
       ('2017-01-01 08:01', 1, 7.3),
       ('2017-01-02 08:01', 2, 0.23),
       ('2018-07-02 08:01', 87, 0.0),
       ('2018-07-01 06:01', 13, 3.1),
       ('2018-07-01 09:11', 90, 10303.12),
       ('2018-07-01 08:01', 29, 64),
       ('2019-07-02 08:01', 87, 0.0),
       ('2019-07-01 06:01', 13, 3.1),
       ('2019-07-01 09:11', 90, 10303.12),
       ('2019-07-01 08:01', 29, 64);

SELECT compress_chunk(show_chunks('hyper'));
```

The last query compressed all chunks and gives result:

```
            compress_chunk
-----------------------------------------
 _timescaledb_internal._hyper_3_13_chunk
 _timescaledb_internal._hyper_3_14_chunk
 _timescaledb_internal._hyper_3_15_chunk
 _timescaledb_internal._hyper_3_16_chunk
 _timescaledb_internal._hyper_3_17_chunk
 _timescaledb_internal._hyper_3_18_chunk
(6 rows)
```

Let's aim to insert the following value:

```sql
INSERT INTO hyper VALUES ('2018-07-02 06:01', 12, 5.1);
```

which fails with:

```
ERROR:  insert/update/delete not permitted on chunk "_hyper_3_16_chunk"
HINT:  Make sure the chunk is not compressed.
```

The following query allows to find chunks satisfying the time value:

```sql
SELECT c.chunk_name
FROM (SELECT show_chunks('hyper') AS chunk_name
    EXCEPT (SELECT show_chunks('hyper', older_than => '2018-07-02 06:01'::timestamptz))
    EXCEPT (SELECT show_chunks('hyper', newer_than => '2018-07-02 06:01'::timestamptz))) AS c
JOIN timescaledb_information.compressed_chunk_stats i ON i.chunk_name = c.chunk_name;
```

with result of 2 chunks as there is one space dimension with 2 partitions:

```
               chunk_name
-----------------------------------------
 _timescaledb_internal._hyper_3_15_chunk
 _timescaledb_internal._hyper_3_16_chunk
(2 rows)
```

**Update with more details**
Selecting a chunk further for the given `device` value can be done by checking range values stored in `_timescaledb_catalog.dimension_slice`. Matching the selected chunks to their dimension_slices are done by joining with `_timescaledb_catalog.chunk` on `chunk_name`,  `_timescaledb_catalog.chunk_constraint` on `chunk_id` and finally with `_timescaledb_catalog.dimension_slice` on `dimension_slice_id`. The selection of dimension slice is done on the range, which uses hashed values. This condition is the same as the constraint of the chunk table. For example, use `d _chunk_name`:

```
\d _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_1_chunk
           Table "_timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_1_chunk"
 Column |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 time   | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 device | integer                  |           |          |
 value  | double precision         |           |          |
Indexes:
    "_hyper_1_1_chunk_hyper_device_time_idx" btree (device, "time" DESC)
    "_hyper_1_1_chunk_hyper_time_idx" btree ("time" DESC)
Check constraints:
    "constraint_1" CHECK ("time" >= '2016-12-29 01:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone AND "time" < '2017-01-05 01:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone)
    "constraint_2" CHECK (_timescaledb_internal.get_partition_hash(device) < 1073741823)
Triggers:
    compressed_chunk_insert_blocker BEFORE INSERT ON _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_1_chunk FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE _timescaledb_internal.chunk_dml_blocker()
Inherits: hyper
```

The following query demonstrates how to use internal catalogs on the above query result to get the exact chunk to uncompress:

```sql
SELECT ch.chunk_name
FROM (SELECT c.chunk_name
      FROM (SELECT show_chunks('hyper') AS chunk_name
           EXCEPT (SELECT show_chunks('hyper', older_than => '2018-07-02 06:01'::timestamptz))
           EXCEPT (SELECT show_chunks('hyper', newer_than => '2018-07-02 06:01'::timestamptz))) AS c
        JOIN timescaledb_information.compressed_chunk_stats i ON i.chunk_name = c.chunk_name
      WHERE i.compression_status = 'Compressed') ch
  JOIN _timescaledb_catalog.chunk cc ON chunk_name::text = schema_name||'.'||table_name
  JOIN _timescaledb_catalog.chunk_constraint ON cc.id = chunk_id
  JOIN _timescaledb_catalog.dimension_slice ds ON dimension_slice_id = ds.id
WHERE range_start <= _timescaledb_internal.get_partition_hash(12) 
    AND range_end > _timescaledb_internal.get_partition_hash(12);
```

The result of the query is:

```
               chunk_name
-----------------------------------------
 _timescaledb_internal._hyper_3_16_chunk
(1 row)
```

This statement can be turned into a function, which will take `time` and `device` values as input.

**The final query answering the question**, now just modify the query to call decompress_chunk:

```sql
SELECT decompress_chunk(ch.chunk_name)
FROM (SELECT c.chunk_name
      FROM (SELECT show_chunks('hyper') AS chunk_name
           EXCEPT (SELECT show_chunks('hyper', older_than => '2018-07-02 06:01'::timestamptz))
           EXCEPT (SELECT show_chunks('hyper', newer_than => '2018-07-02 06:01'::timestamptz))) AS c
        JOIN timescaledb_information.compressed_chunk_stats i ON i.chunk_name = c.chunk_name
WHERE i.compression_status = 'Compressed') ch
JOIN _timescaledb_catalog.chunk cc ON chunk_name::text = schema_name||'.'||table_name
JOIN _timescaledb_catalog.chunk_constraint ON cc.id = chunk_id
JOIN _timescaledb_catalog.dimension_slice ds ON dimension_slice_id = ds.id
WHERE range_start <= _timescaledb_internal.get_partition_hash(12) 
    AND range_end > _timescaledb_internal.get_partition_hash(12);
```

And the insert will work successfully:

```sql
INSERT INTO hyper VALUES ('2018-07-02 06:01', 12, 5.1);
-- INSERT 0 1
```

**Backfill use case**: if the insertion is a part of backfilling data, then there is a procedure `decompress_backfill` in [timescaledb-extras project](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-extras), which decompresses necessary chunks and backfills data from a source table.

#### Note that the query answering the question might stop to work in new versions of TimescaleDB, since it uses internal catalogs.

I am not aware if it is possible to achieve the same with using only public interface.

Comment: Thank you very much @k_rus. The only part I don't follow is regarding the device. Can you explain again how you are selecting chunks relevant to device X?

Comment: OK, I get it. Successive JOINs retrieve info about the chunk, starting with name, through ID, to all constraints on the the chunk. Then it focuses on partitioning related constraints and selects the one that is related to the device (in this example) using the WHERE statement. What seems like magic is the last step - how did you know to use .get_partition_hash(12)? Is this covered in documentation?

Lastly, I still don't understand how I would plug in the device I am interested in.

Comment: @WhiteStork Thank you for the question, I didn't go in this detail. I learned the constraint check condition from `pg_constraint`, since each chunk has constraints for the query planner to choose the correct chunk. I will update my answer.

Comment: Actually it's easier just to do `\d _timescaledb_internal._hyper_3_16_chunk`

Comment: Also I forgot to mention that this solution might require adaptation in future versions.